# Android how to find all duplicate file in device

Tags: android, file, duplicates

How to i can find all data file duplicate and show list file duplicate in RecyclerView. I only can get all file in device but not found duplicate file.
I have see this question and still can't find all file duplicate
[How to find duplicate files from programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233867/how-to-find-duplicate-files-from-programmatically)
My code :

```
// create class Duplicate
class Duplicate(
   var duplicateFiles: ArrayList<DuplicateFile>
) : Serializable
// create class DuplicateFile
class DuplicateFile(
    var file: File,
    var isSelect: Boolean
)
// in MainActivity i create 2 function to try get all file duplicate
MainActivity{
        onCreate{
            //I don't know what parameter to pass in the 2 parentheses in the method below and i write ???
            getDuplicateFiles(???)
        }
        fun getDuplicateFiles(files: List<File?>): List<Duplicate?>? {
        val hashmap: HashMap<String, Duplicate> = HashMap()
        val duplicateHashSet: HashMap<String, Duplicate> = HashMap()
        for (file in files) {
            val md5: String = getFileMD5ToString(file)
            if (hashmap.containsKey(md5)) {
                val original = hashmap[md5]
                if (duplicateHashSet.containsKey(md5)) {
                    var fileList= arrayListOf<DuplicateFile>()
                    if (original != null) {
                        fileList = original.duplicateFiles
                        fileList.add(
                            DuplicateFile(original.duplicateFiles[0].file, false)
                        )
                    } else {
                        fileList = ArrayList()
                        fileList.add(DuplicateFile(file!!, false))
                    }
                } else {
                    val fileList= arrayListOf<DuplicateFile>()
                    if (original!!.duplicateFiles == null) {
                        original.duplicateFiles = ArrayList()
                    }
                    fileList.add(DuplicateFile(original.duplicateFiles[0].file, false))
                    fileList.add(DuplicateFile(file!!, false))
                    duplicateHashSet[md5] = Duplicate(fileList)
                }
            } else {
                val fileList= arrayListOf<DuplicateFile>()
                fileList.add(DuplicateFile(file!!, false))
                hashmap[md5] = Duplicate(fileList)
            }
        }
        var list: List<Duplicate?>? = null
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            list = ArrayList(duplicateHashSet.values)
        }
        Log.d("kkkkaa",list?.size.toString())
        return list
    }

    fun getAllFiles(context: Context): List<File>? {
        return try {
            val files: MutableList<File> = ArrayList()
            val pdf = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf")
            val doc = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("doc")
            val docx = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("docx")
            val xlsx = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("xlsx")
            val txt = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("txt")
            val ppt = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("ppt")
            val pptx = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pptx")
            val png = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("png")
            val jpg = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("jpg")
            val jpeg = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("jpeg")
            val gif = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("gif")
            val mp4 = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp4")
            val mkv = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mkv")
            val avi = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("avi")
            val apk = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("apk")
            val mp3 = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp3")
            val table = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
            val data = arrayOf(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA)
            val where = (MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?" + " OR "
                    + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?")
            val args = arrayOf(
                pdf,
                doc,
                docx,
                xlsx,
                txt,
                ppt,
                pptx,
                png,
                jpg,
                jpeg,
                gif,
                mp4,
                mkv,
                avi,
                apk,
                mp3
            )
            val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(table, data, where, args, null)
            if (cursor != null) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    val file = File(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(data[0])))
                    files.add(file)
                }
                cursor.close()
            }
            files
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            ArrayList()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you plan to check for duplicates regulary - create DB with file path, size, last modification timestamp and optional MD5 hash of content (initially set it to null). Check those files, which size matches, create hashes and save to DB. If hashes match - that is duplicates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find duplicate files from programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233867/how-to-find-duplicate-files-from-programmatically)

Comment: @Dmytro Rostopira no bro. I too try that way but wrong code and can't get all file duplicate

Comment: I don't see any attempt to compare files in your question. Provide appropriate code which doesn't work

Comment: Yes bro, i have updated my code in the question. Please check my question. Tks !